# DirectX Version on Windows XP SP3

Tags: directx, windows-xp-sp3

What is the version of DirectX that is installed by default with Windows XP SP3? Google did not yield convincing results on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a [useful page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb173024(VS.85).aspx) in MSDN that confirms the version of DirectX included with each Windows OS and Service Pack release. It seems that the last change for XP was in SP2 - which was indeed DirectX 9.0c, as Raghu states.

Answer (score 2):

i guess it is 9.0c.

You can check the same by running the command dxdiag

Comment: Thanks. Are there any release notes I could use to back the 9.0c stand? I don't have a clean XP SP3 box so I couldn't use dxdiag.

Comment: DX9.0c is included starting with XP SP2. On earlier OSes it can be installed manually. DX10 is included starting with Vista (and DX10.1 with Vista SP1).

Comment: Hi Vulcan, i checked but couldn't find any. But it is 9.0c for sure.